# Using PHPmailer didn't get mail in webmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I try to sent mail on submitting the form using the SMTP server. I get mail on my Gmail account but didn't get mail on webmail.

Is it an SMTP server issue or webmail?

What can I do to send mail on webmail?
Have to something remaining config in webmail?

Below I tried code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '**********';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '**********';                 // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                      // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                              // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('info@abc.com','ABC');
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);           // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'ABC - Register Successfully';
$mail->Body = "
    <h4>Dear $name,</h4>
    <p>Thank you! Your registration has been successful.</p>
    
    <p>If you need any help or query, please feel free to drop an email using the following email address: <strong>info@abc.com</strong></p>
    <p>We appreciate your patience. </p>
    <h4>Thanking You,</h4>
";
$mail->send();
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is GMail an allowed sender for the given address?

Comment: I get mail on my Gmail account but didn't get mail on my webmail account

Comment: Have to something remaining config in webmail?